# RavenDB won't fill Id-field

Tags: f#, ravendb

I'm new to the NoSql thing and am playing with (embedded) RavenDb in F#.
Problem is: when I query a record from the store it won't fill in the Id field (is null) - the rest will is correct.

Is this the expected behavior and why?

Here is the test-code with the problem:

```
open Xunit
open System.Linq

module RavenDbPOC =

    type SimpleTestData =
        {
            Id : string
            Name : string
            Value : int
        }

    let testId = "12345"
    let testName = "MaxMustermann"
    let testValue = 42

    let createSampleData() = { Id = testId; Name = testName; Value = testValue }

    let createRandomStoreName() =
        let baseName = "ProofOfConceptData"
        let id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        sprintf @"c:\temp\%s_%s" baseName id

    let useRavenSession(store : Raven.Client.IDocumentStore, saveChanges : bool) doWorkWith  =
        use session = store.OpenSession()
        let result = doWorkWith session
        if saveChanges then session.SaveChanges()
        result

    let initializeDocumentStore() =
        let storeName = createRandomStoreName()
        let documentStore = new Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddableDocumentStore()
        documentStore.DataDirectory <- storeName
        let store = documentStore.Initialize()
        store

    let createIn store data =
        useRavenSession (store, true) (fun session -> session.Store(data))

    let loadId (id : string) store : SimpleTestData =
        useRavenSession (store, false) (fun session -> session.Load(id))

    [<Fact>]
    let CanReadStoredData() =
        use store = initializeDocumentStore()
        createSampleData() |> createIn store
        let data = store |> loadId testId
        Assert.Equal(testId, data.Id)
        Assert.Equal(testName, data.Name)
        Assert.Equal(testValue, data.Value)
```

the test will throw on the first assert (expected "12345", actual ).
If I pass a wrong Id the function will return  (as excpected) - all the other fields are correct

As Ayende asked: here is a screenshot of the data-class in ObjectBrowser. The Properties are read-only:
[image]

and it's more or less the same as the sample on [github](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/tree/master/Samples/Raven.Sample.FSharp)

UPDATE 2:

changed the code to use the following data-objects:

```
    type TestData(id : System.Guid, name : string, value : int) =
        let mutable _id = id
        member x.Id with get() = _id and set(id) = _id <- id
        member x.Name with get() = name
        member x.Value with get() = value
```

AFAIK the only difference that is important here is that now the Id-property is writable, rest just the same and yes ... this is working.
BUT it's almost the opposite of what I normaly want. I want the Id-field to be readonly and maybe to write the others not the other way ...

I guess it's at a point where I should open a ticket or something with RavenDB - what do you guys think?

Comment: What does SimpleTestData looks like if it was C# type?

Comment: It seems to be related to the fact that F# records are classes with properties as readonly. I suggest you to try to make the F# record as a "class type" with public properties

Comment: to be honest: I don't like designing by tools ... so I'd rather change my repository-load to something like {result with id = queryId} to fill in the only missing piece. The other fields are initialized after all - and the sample suggests that this is possible. BTW sample indicated that we can get a new Id just by saying Id = null before saving - this doesn't work too (after this you can't even fetch the document anymore because Id = null)

Comment: well...doh - this of course is not possible if I query in any other way than for the Id (or even if I want to enumerate all) ... guess I have to take the "long" road. But: is this a BUG or *indented*?

Comment: just as a test I added another string property "SameId" to the record and initialized it to the same value. After changing the test to use this property all lights turn green, so this has to be some strange artifact with RavenDBs handling of a property named Id ... I guess it want's to set it not using the constructor. Maybe to give a unique Id on <null>?

Comment: tested the same thing with System.Guid instead of string - same problem, the Guid is set to empty. But found the following exception while debuging: A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentFileNotFoundException' occurred in Esent.Interop.DLL / with stacktrace:    at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.Check(Int32 err) in C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\Api.cs:line 2739 - maybe this helps @Ayende ?

Comment: ... the Exception is thrown by the Initialize-Method of the DocumentStore and this might be ok since there will be no files on disc at this point

Comment: From the RavenDB docs "Entity ids are only set when the SaveChanges method is called. " - this would explain your behaviour quite nicely.  Taken from http://ravendb.net/tutorials/hello-world

Comment: yes you are right - but why publish a F#-sample suggesting otherwise? Well can live with this (you have to be pragmatic right?) - it's only a for a little pet/weekend project of mine but from a design view I wanted the Id to be immutable ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RavenDb client seems to have a problem with properties that are readonly as an id (I don't fully understand why this is, you may want to raise it as an issue on their mailing list). However, the work around is easy. Just change the id field to mutable then everything will work as expected. It's just a case of making the following change:

```
type SimpleTestData =
    {
        mutable Id : string
        Name : string
        Value : int
    }
```

And it's generally better to set the id to null to allow ravendb to generate the id:

```
let createSampleData() = { Id = null; Name = testName; Value = testValue }
```

Finally, one gotcha when using records is the ravendb client stores a copy of loaded types in it's cache and attempts to track changes. This doesn't work too well if you try and make a copy of a record and resave it. To get round this you need to evict the previously stored type:

```
let myRecord = session.Load("simpletestdata/123")
let myRecord' = { myRecord with Value = 52 }
session.Advanced.Evict myRecord
session.Store myRecord'
session.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: oh - thanks a lot. Didn't even know that you can make a recordfield mutable

Comment: one question: ravendb won't save to the same document if I give the same ID? Really - that's gameover for me. Impractical to use immutable structures through transformations and allways have to provide the one from ravendb in the beginning - that pushes the hole design to be "ravendb-aware" - not even EF has this problem ;)

Comment: I suspect it wouldn't be that hard to remove this problem. I would encourage you to send a message to their mailing list or to send them a patch. I keep meaning to do so, I just haven't got round to it yet. They're generally quite responsive.

Comment: I don't know if I can really make a "patch" myself but I will try and look into the code - thank you

Comment: I raised this with the flocks at RavenDb today and they already created a patch to fix the problem. See: http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/d7ff7b8272772581

Comment: wow - thank you - I feel like I should give you some bounty or something (is this possible after I marked?)

Comment: Don't think so but don't worry about it, I send the message because it something I wanted for myself, just hadn't got round to it.